# in Powershell saving xml variable to a file gives syntax errors

Tags: xml, powershell, save

need to do simple task and new to Powershell - I'd like to properly format an XML file

eg: I have an xml file like:

```xml
<first><second><third>hello world</third></second></first>
```

and like to properly format it and save it to a new file so did:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content .\test.xml
```

but when I try to save it to a file like:

```
$xml.Save(test2.xml)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
At line:1 char:11
+ $xml.Save(test2.xml)
+           ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:11
+ $xml.Save(test2.xml)
+           ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'test2.xml' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:20
+ $xml.Save(test2.xml)
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

tried many different combinations but none worked.
I know the first line worked fine since running the following line gives proper output:

```
$xml.Save([System.Console]::Out)
```

any tip is greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a variable for the file name, or quotes for string literal. That is. `.save('test2.xml')` or `.save($newFile)`.

Comment: thanks @vonPryz -  used `$xml.Save('c:\temp\test2.xml') and worked - I gave it full path which made it less confusing. Thanks again

Comment: @user3578994 if you ever wanna pass a relative path to a native .NET method, `.Save("$PWD\filename.ext")` or `.Save((Join-Path $PWD filename.ext))`